# Qual a diferença entre Implicação Lógica e Equivalência Lógica?

Tags: matemática, lógica

Estou estudando lógica matemática e lógica de programação, e gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre Implicação Lógica e Equivalência Lógica?

Answer (score 12):

## Implicação lógica

Partindo da [minha resposta na sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137207/132). Temos que uma implicação lógica é uma cláusula na seguinte forma:

> *p* → *q*

E ela significa:

> Se *p* for verdadeiro, então *q* também é verdadeiro.

Mas e se *p* for falso? Bem, neste caso, nada podemos dizer sobre *q* sem maiores informações. Ou seja, *q* pode ou não ser verdadeiro.

Isso contrasta com a equivalência lógica que se segue:

## Equivalência lógica

> *p* ↔ *q*

Que significa:

> *p* é verdadeiro se, e somente se, *q* também for verdadeiro.

Neste caso, se *p* for falso, então *q* também será falso, afinal de contas *q* só poderá ser verdadeiro se *p* também for.

Isso é chamado de equivalência por causa do seguinte:

> Se *p* for verdadeiro, *q* também é verdadeiro.
>   Se *p* for falso, *q* também é falso.

Ou simplificando:

> *p* = *q*

Acontece que a **igualdade** em lógica é chamada de **equivalência**. Para a igualdade usa-se o **`=`**, enquanto que para a equivalência, usa-se o **`↔`**. Isso poderia parecer algo bobo em princípio, mas serve para que expressões lógicas com subexpresssões matemáticas como a se segue possam ser lidas de forma precisa sem precisar de muitos parênteses:

> *a* = 0 ∨ *b* = 0 ↔ *ab* = 0

Em relação a implicação temos o seguinte:

> *a* → *b*
>   *b* → *a*
>   ----
>   ∴ *a* ↔ *b*

E é por isso inclusive que é utilizado o símbolo **`↔`**, pois a equivalência lógica pode também ser interpretada como uma implicação nos dois sentidos.

E obviamente a demonstração pode também ser feita no sentido contrário:

> *a* ↔ *b*
>   ----
>   ∴ *a* → *b* ∧ *b* → *a*

## Ou-exclusivo

Por fim, ainda temos o ou-exclusivo, que é o exato oposto da equivalência. Uma forma de apresentá-lo é assim:

> Ou *p* é verdadeiro, ou *q* é verdadeiro, mas não ambos.

Ora, neste caso, não é difícil concluir que isso significa que se somente um deles pode ser verdadeiro, então quando um for verdadeiro, o outro automaticamente será falso e quando um for falso, o outro automaticamente será verdadeiro. E portanto, o ou-exclusivo significa isso:

> *p* ≠ *q*

Mas, novamente, para não precisarmos de muitos parênteses em expressões lógicas
com subexpressões matemáticas, usa-se algum outro símbolo para denotar o ou-exclusivo. Os mais comuns que vejo por aí são **`⊻`** e **`⊗`**, embora existam outros.

Answer (score 8):

A "Implicação Lógica" é estabelecida entre dois conceitos ou proposições, de tal forma que a afirmação da verdade de um deles conduz à inferência necessária da veracidade do outro. Ela indica que uma condição deve ser satisfeita necessariamente para que a outra seja verdadeira.

Ex: `if...else`

A "Equivalência Lógica"  é relação de igualdade lógica ou implicação mútua entre duas proposições, de tal forma que cada uma delas só é verdadeira se a outra também o for.

Ex: `x===y`