# Qual a diferença entre Modus Ponens e Modus Tollens?

Tags: matemática, lógica, tabela-verdade

Novamente no estudo da lógica matemática, como diferenciar uma proposição *modus ponens* de uma *modus tollens*?

Answer (score 20):

*Modus ponens* e *modus tollens* são formas de se resolver implicações lógicas. Uma implicação lógica é uma cláusula na seguinte forma:

> *p* → *q*

E ela significa:

> Se *p* for verdadeiro, então *q* também é verdadeiro.

---

## *Modus ponens*

O *modus ponens* ocorre quando temos isso:

> *p* → *q*
>   *p*

O que significa:

> Se *p* for verdadeiro, então *q* também é verdadeiro.
>   *p* é verdadeiro.

E portanto, a consequência lógica é:

> *q* é verdadeiro.

E assim, o *modus ponens* é definido desta forma:

> *p* → *q*
>   *p*
>   -----
>   ∴ *q*

---

## *Modus tollens*

Já o *modus tollens* ocorre quando temos isso:

> *p* → *q*
>   ¬*q*

O que significa:

> Se *p* for verdadeiro, então *q* também é verdadeiro.
>   *q* é falso.

E portanto, a consequência lógica é:

> *p* é falso.

O motivo para isso é porque se *p* fosse verdadeiro, então *q* também teria que ser verdadeiro. Mas como *q* é falso, logo não é possível que *p* seja verdadeiro, e portanto *p* só pode ser falso.

E assim, o *modus tollens* é definido desta forma:

> *p* → *q*
>   ¬*q*
>   -----
>   ∴ ¬*p*

---

## Diferenciação

Assim, sendo a principal forma de diferenciar é que:

- No *modus ponens*, você usa a implicação para provar que a **consequência** é **verdadeira** ao demonstrar que a **premissa** é **verdadeira**.
- No *modus tollens*, você usa a implicação para provar que a **premissa** é **falsa** ao demonstrar que a **consequência** é **falsa**.

Ou seja, são quase que opostos, vendo-se sobre esse ângulo.

Além disso, dá para dizer que o processo matemático de demonstração por inferência é uma aplicação do *modus ponens*, enquanto que o processo por trás da demonstração por redução ao absurdo é uma aplicação do *modus tollens*.

---

<sub>NOTA: O símbolo "∴" é lido como "*portanto*", "*logo*", "*conclui-se que*" ou "*e então*".</sub>

Comment: Ótima resposta! +1

Comment: Eu navegando aqui pelo stackoverflow acho coisas que nunca veria  em toda minha vida. Vou até pesquisar mas sobre o assunto .

Comment: cool! +1 (e ainda por cima com bom aspecto gráfico!